# What is the format for a write concern tag set in a MongoDB connection string?

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to use a tag set to set a write concern in MongoDB as described in the docs:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#uri.w

However, I can't find a format for how the tags should look in the connection string. I've tried:

`mongodb://hostname/?w=use:production`

and several variations, but I always get the error:

`exception: unrecognized getLastError mode: use:production`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure getLastErrorModes in the replica set configuration.

For instance....

```
conf.settings = { getLastErrorModes: { MultipleDC : { "dc.va": 1, "dc.gto": 1}}}
```

then you can use the uri like this..

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test?w=MultipleDC
```

See here...
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#configure-tag-sets-for-custom-multi-data-center-write-concern-mode